# Cloudwatch alert on any instance creation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I would like to send out alerts and create logs any time an instance is created within an aws account.  The instances in the account are mostly static and are rarely changed, so an alert should go off when an unauthorized change is made.

How can I create a cloudwatch alarm that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 options:

**Option 1** - You write code

- Enable CloudTrail
- Have S3 trigger a Lambda function for PutObject (gets triggered whenever CloudTrail delivers events)
- Write a Lambda function that reads the passed S3 object, looks for RunInstances event and sends a mail including instance name, instance id, who launched the instance etc., using  AWS SES
- You pay for CloudTrail+S3 only (SES cost is negligible)

**Option 2** - Let AWS do everything

- Enable CloudTrail
- Have CloudTrail logs delivered to CloudWatch
- Add an alarm in CloudWatch to send you an alert using SNS when CloudWatch detects `RunInstances`
- You pay for CloudTrail+S3+CloudWatch
- More info: [Sending Events to CloudWatch Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/send-cloudtrail-events-to-cloudwatch-logs.html)

Comment: Yep that works a cloudwatch + sns email does the trick.  This is the cloudwatch json that I used to make this happen:  `{
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "ec2.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "RunInstances"
    ]
  }
}`